# Kubernetes: Managing environment config

Tags: docker, environment-variables, yaml, kubernetes

The reccomended method for managing environment configuration containers running in a pod is through the use of `configmap`. [See the docs here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/configmap/).

This is great although we have containers that require massive amounts of environment variables, this will only expand in the future. Using the prescribed `configmap` method this become unweildy and hard to manage.

For example a simple deplyment file becomes massive:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-api
  labels:
    name: my-app-api
    environment: staging
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    name: my-app-api
    environment: staging
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app-api
spec:
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: my-app-api
        environment: staging
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app-api
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: myapp/my-app-api:latest
        ports:
            - containerPort: 80
        env:
            - name: API_HOST
              value: XXXXXXXXXXX
            - name: API_ENV
              value: XXXXXXXXXXX
            - name: API_DEBUG
              value: XXXXXXXXXXX
            - name: API_KEY
              value: XXXXXXXXXXX
            - name: EJ_API_ENDPOINT
              value: XXXXXXXXXXX
            - name: WEB_HOST
              value: XXXXXXXXXXX
            - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY
              value: XXXXXXXXXXX
            - name: AWS_SECRET_KEY
              value: XXXXXXXXXXX
            - name: CDN
              value: XXXXXXXXXXX
            - name: STRIPE_KEY
              value: XXXXXXXXXXX
            - name: STRIPE_SECRET
              value: XXXXXXXXXXX
            - name: DB_HOST
              value: XXXXXXXXXXX
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: XXXXXXXXXXX
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              value: XXXXXXXXXXX
            - name: REDIS_HOST
              value: XXXXXXXXXXX
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: my-registry-key
```

Are there alternate easy to inject a central environment configuration?

**UPDATE**

This was proposed for `1.5` although did not make the cut and looks like it will be included in `1.6`. Fingers crossed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [proposal](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/26299) currently targeted for 1.5 that aims to make this easier. As proposed, you would be able to pull all variables from a ConfigMap in one go, without having to spell out each one separately.

If implemented, it would allow you to do something like this:

*Warning: This doesn't actually work yet!*

ConfigMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  space-ships: 1
  ship-type: battle-cruiser
  weapon: laser-cannon
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: space-config
```

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: space-simulator
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: space-simulator
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: space-simulator
        image: foo/space-simulator
      # This is the magic piece that would allow you to avoid all that boilerplate!
      - envFrom:
        configMap: space-config
```

Comment: Exactly what we'd need. Any ETA on v1.5 hahaa?

Comment: End of 2016, so hopefully not too long to wait, assuming this actually makes it in.